# What are the iOS 8.0+ NSCalendarUnits?

Tags: ios8, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I noticed that all the `NSCalendarUnits` (e.g., `NSDayCalendarUnit`) is officially deprecated as of iOS 8.0.

What is the replacement?

Answer (score 8):

They are replaced by (just peek into SDK):

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSCalendarUnit) {
        NSCalendarUnitEra                = kCFCalendarUnitEra,
        NSCalendarUnitYear               = kCFCalendarUnitYear,
        NSCalendarUnitMonth              = kCFCalendarUnitMonth,
        NSCalendarUnitDay                = kCFCalendarUnitDay,
        NSCalendarUnitHour               = kCFCalendarUnitHour,
        NSCalendarUnitMinute             = kCFCalendarUnitMinute,
        NSCalendarUnitSecond             = kCFCalendarUnitSecond,
        NSCalendarUnitWeekday            = kCFCalendarUnitWeekday,
        NSCalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal     = kCFCalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal,
        NSCalendarUnitQuarter            NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = kCFCalendarUnitQuarter,
        NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth        NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0) = kCFCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth,
        NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear         NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0) = kCFCalendarUnitWeekOfYear,
        NSCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear  NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0) = kCFCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear,
        NSCalendarUnitNanosecond         NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0) = (1 << 15),
        NSCalendarUnitCalendar           NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0) = (1 << 20),
        NSCalendarUnitTimeZone           NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0) = (1 << 21),

    NSEraCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitEra instead") = NSCalendarUnitEra,
    NSYearCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitYear instead") = NSCalendarUnitYear,
    NSMonthCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitMonth instead") = NSCalendarUnitMonth,
    NSDayCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitDay instead") = NSCalendarUnitDay,
    NSHourCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitHour instead") = NSCalendarUnitHour,
    NSMinuteCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitMinute instead") = NSCalendarUnitMinute,
    NSSecondCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitSecond instead") = NSCalendarUnitSecond,
    NSWeekCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth or NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear, depending on which you mean") = kCFCalendarUnitWeek,
    NSWeekdayCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitWeekday instead") = NSCalendarUnitWeekday,
    NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal instead") = NSCalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal,
    NSQuarterCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_6, 10_10, 4_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitQuarter instead") = NSCalendarUnitQuarter,
    NSWeekOfMonthCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_7, 10_10, 5_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth instead") = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth,
    NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_7, 10_10, 5_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear instead") = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear,
    NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_7, 10_10, 5_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear instead") = NSCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear,
    NSCalendarCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_7, 10_10, 4_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitCalendar instead") = NSCalendarUnitCalendar,
    NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_7, 10_10, 4_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitTimeZone instead") = NSCalendarUnitTimeZone,
};
```

Comment: Thanks.  Shall note it.